# getting mysqli error in modx evolution

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, modx, modx-evolution

I have transferred one modx website evolution version to another domain but on another domain after doing changes  in config, its manager is working but main website means front view is not working and giving me error.

« MODx Parse Error »
MODx encountered the following error while attempting to parse the requested resource:
« PHP Parse Error »

PHP error debug

```
  Error:    mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead  
  Error type/ Nr.:  - 8192   
  File:     C:\xampp\htdocs\mpelimited\manager\includes\extenders\dbapi.mysql.class.inc.php  
  Line:     93   
  Line 93 source:   else $this->conn = mysql_connect($host, $uid, $pwd, true);   

Parser timing
  MySQL:    0.0000 s    (0 Requests)
  PHP:  0.0250 s     
  Total:    0.0250 s
```

Here is screenshot
http://prntscr.com/a7udni

How can i resolve this issue in MODx version        1.0.5

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Resolve this by not using `mysql_connect`. Did you read the error? That method [doesn't even exist in PHP 7](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). Answer right there: "use mysqli or PDO instead". If this is a limitation of MODx, you might need to update the version.

Comment: I think the error message tells you how to resolve the issue. See this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli

Comment: How can i update modx without losing any data

Answer (score 1):

Please update MODX Evolution to 1.0.15 or to the upcoming 1.1.0

Comment: How can i update modx . Will it affect my website previous working , chunks , snippets , modules which are working

Comment: There is a detailed upgrade entry in the MODX Evolution documentation https://rtfm.modx.com/evolution/1.0/administration/upgrading

Answer (score 0):

here is sollution
https://toster.ru/q/125593

and works,
as temp solution